# Inject raw fragmented packets

Tags: windows, code-injection, packet, packet-injection

I'm trying to inject a fragment packet and i can't.
I see that if i have one udp packet witch has been split to two **Ip** packets 
i can't inject only the second part, my operation system (windows Xp) seems to wait for the first part before it injects the two fragmented packets.
I don't have routers in the way or something like that, because I'm sending the packets to another computer which connected to my computer in cross.
I have tried it with 3 different kinds of NIC.
I'm sure that the packets are waiting in my computer (the sender) I have proved it if you want I will post the experiment.
I have tried to play with the flags and nothing.
If i try to send only the first part on one computer it seems to work (weird) but I can't explain it.
please don't tell my to switch to Linux it is really problematic.

Thank you all.
It is really important.

Answer (score 0):

If the use of Windows is not crucial, I have successfully used tcpreplay on a Linux machine, run as root, to read arbitrary packets from a pcap file and send them out on a network interface.

```
http://tcpreplay.synfin.net
```

The tcpreplay web page says that it is available for Cygwin running on Windows as well, although I have not tried that version before.

```
http://www.cygwin.com
```